# How to pass Russian characters in Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, locale, java-7

I am using Java's `ProcessBuilder` to call an exe with different arguments.

The exe is also built by me.

In certain scenarios, I need to pass arguments to exe which contains Russian characters. But when the exe gets this argument it comes as garbage characters instead of Russian characters.

Is there any specific thing I need to do while passing Russian characters as arguments in `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Java strngs use Unicide and thus can contain Russian characters. The problem will be the encoding used by your operating system, which you do not mention.

Comment: @Raedwald - That could very well be issue. But how to overcome this problem if my java program and exe both are on english winodows OS but argument has russian characters?

Comment: did you know you that can simply use unicode characters in your java string? just try String str = "\u0447";

Comment: @MartinFrank Do you know how can I convert russian string to unicode in java? And how would my exe will convert it back to russian character? or would it automatically get converted?

Comment: Well I got how to convert string to unicode in java. But how can I convert unicode to russian character in c code which is generating my exe?

Comment: maybe you can translate the letters, i can't do any kyrill, but have a look at those tables http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script#Computer_encoding

Comment: "how can I convert russian string to unicode in java" Java strings are already in Unicode. You need to learn a bit more about character sets and character encoding, to understand the problem you have and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
String args = "your arguments";
byte bytes[] = myString.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: how are you passing the arguments to the exe?

Answer (score 0):

Using unicode you can represent russian Strings in Java...

```
String str = "\u0447\u0416\u0444\u0414\u0409"; // чЖфДЉ
```

(taken from http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf , see link above)
but honestly, i can't speak/write/understand any russian, sorry ^^

and even worse, i'm not sure if this will even help you :-$

Answer (score 0):

So you are not on a Russian system. And the exe is for ANSI OEM encoding.
This is not problematic, but as for cross-compilation, it is hard to verify things.
Simply interprete the Russian single-byte encoding as your own Windows single-byte encoding. It looks as garbage - so what.

Pass the "garbage" and collect the resulting "garbage" in a file.
Then that file is in the same encoding as the origin, and everything is fine.

Try verifying with a multi-encoding programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit. Make sure you start editing a **copy** of the files. The most likely encoding for Russian is **Windows-1251**.

***Problem 1:***

They gave Unicode text, UTF-8 (multibyte sequences for a non-ASCII char) or UTF-16LE (two bytes per char). Your exe might have limits, so then better convert it to Windows-1251:

Reading

```
Path russianFile = Paths.get("C:/russian-utf8.txt");
byte[] ruBytes = Files.readAllBytes(russianFile);
String russian = new String(ruBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Write the same.

***Problem 2:***

The exe writes special characters. This will become garbage characters, or worse, a Cyrillic letter.

***Problem 3:***

Validation takes place, maybe prohibiting non-alphanumeric input like Cyrillic letters.